# My simulation is not never finishing and it is taking so much time?

Tags: simulation, date-and-time, differential-equations

I am running simple code which involves calculation of two first order differential equations.It is taking so much time and i am unable to get the results as the simulation is never finishing.

```
Remove["Global`*"]

(* Parameters *)

a = 10^-9;
\[Epsilon]0 = 8.85*10^-12;
k1 = 10;
k2 = 10;
e = 1.6*10^-19;
u = ((1/3)*e) ;     (*jouls *)
h = 6.6*10^-34;
\[Delta] = 6.6*10^-9;
d = 100*10^-9;
r = 1;
m = 9*10^-31;
f = 10000;
v0 = 7.5;
T = 5/f;
v[t] = v0*Sin[2*\[Pi]*1*t];
c0 = (a*\[Epsilon]0*k1)/d;

(* Equations *)

c = c0/(1 + (((\[Delta]*q1[t])/(d*q[t]))));


(*Q1 and Q2 are assumed separetly but q+ and q- are assumed together*)

eQ = (q[t] + q1[t])/(2*a*\[Epsilon]0*k2);
vk = eQ*\[Delta];


qq = NDSolve[{q'[t] == v[t]/r - q[t]/r*(1/c), 
    q1'[t] == (((q[t] + q1[t])/(2*a*\[Epsilon]0*k2))*\[Delta]), 
    q[0] == 10*10^-9, q1[0] == 10*10^-9}, {q, q1}, {t, 0, 5}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity, AccuracyGoal -> 20];

Plot[Evaluate[q1[t] /. qq], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]

Plot[Evaluate[q[t] /. qq], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is numerical solution necessary? Your equations can be solved analytically by `DSolve`.

Comment: @xzczd. Yes the numerical solution is necessary as I need to plot the end result after computation over certain range of time.

Comment: Well, "need to plot" isn't a reason for using numerical solution. The analytic solution can be used for plotting, too!

Answer (score 4):

The reason it's not finishing is that you set `MaxSteps -> Infinity` with a high `AccuracyGoal`.

We can actually solve this system analytically, by replacing `NDSolve` with `DSolve`:

```
qq = DSolve[{q'[t] == v[t]/r - q[t]/r*(1/c), 
    q1'[t] == (((q[t] + q1[t])/(2*a*ϵ0*k2))*δ), 
    q[0] == 10*10^-9, q1[0] == 10*10^-9}, {q, q1}, t];
```

We can inspect the solution:

```
Rationalize@ComplexExpand[q[t] /. qq]
```

Which contains a lot of terms like

```
1.06621*10^-8 E^(-1.12756*10^12 t)
```

Huge numbers in the exponent like that make me think that this problem is poorly conditioned.  You may want to double-check the values of your constants.

---

The "easy" solution to this problem is just to reduce the integration time.  Leaving the entire code unchanged, we replace the time `5` with a more reasonable value, like `5*^-11`:

```
qq = NDSolve[_, {t, 0, 5*^-11}, ___];

Plot[_, {t, 0, 5*^-11}, ___]
```

This results in the plots:

[image]

[image]

---

You may want to consider changing your units.  Some of Mathematica's integration and plotting algorithms can have trouble with a mixture of very large and very small numbers.

Instead of SI units (meters, seconds, etc.) I would use something like [atomic units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_units) instead.  In this system the relevant constants become a bunch of nice numbers:

- $h = 2\pi$
- $m_e = 1$
- $m_p \approx 1836~m_e$
- $e = 1$
- $k_e = 1$
- $c = \alpha^{-1} \approx 137.035999$
- $\ldots$

This will help prevent you from encountering numerical problems later on down the road, but will also give you a more intuitive feel for the size of the numbers involved.  For example, consider the length $10^{-10}~\text{m}$.  I have no idea what that means, I'd have to think about the exponent for a little while.  In atomic units, the same length is represented by $1.89~a_0$, which I now instantly know is about twice the [radius of the hydrogen atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius).

Comment: My gut feeling is that the solution is ok. This looks like something on the atomic scale expressed in terms of SI, so you end up with picometer wavelengths/THz frequencies (the inverses of which give such coefficients).

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Mathematically the solution is probably fine.  Numerically, the very big and very small numbers can cause problems.  The system will be better-conditioned when described in atomic-scale units.  The other problem is that if this does describe a system that varies on timescales of 10^-12 seconds, then we should expect there to be somewhere around 10^12 steps in the *5 seconds* the integration takes place over.

Comment: Agrred, I probably didn't interpret "poorly conditioned" correctly. Yes, 5 seconds is most likely a completely inappropriate time interval to look at and using atomic-scale units should help avoid some numerical-precision errors.

Comment: Hi all, @LLlAMnYP, Thanks for your response. I really appreciate that. Lets assume all the constant values are correct. Now is there any way to solve this problem. well, The input voltage v[t] frequency and time and the accuracy as well as the max steps can be changed. I need to plot the solution and I thought for that i must use NDSolve..Can I plot using Dsolve? I am new to mathematica. I am sorry for such kinda basic questions.

Comment: @2012rcampion , Thanks for your suggestion. Can you kindly tell me What do you mean by describing the system in atomic scale units ?

Comment: @2012rcampion...Can you kindly explain this Rationalize@ComplexExpand ? what does it do to that long complex mathematical expression.Thanks

Comment: @AKKK Please read the documentation for those functions.  You can access it by pressing `F1` inside Mathematica.  If you still have questions after reading the docs, feel free to ask.

Comment: @AKKKhan, Both `DSolve` and `NDSolve` return functions, the first giving a symbolic solution, but you can readily plot it if you plug in numbers; the second gives an interpolating function, a numerical approximation to the exact solution. As you have already assigned numeric values to all possible parameters, it doesn't matter, what you use. Just plug in the argument to the function and plot it :-)